Weak convergence of predictable quadratic variation
I know under certain conditions, if a sequence of processes $X^n$ weakly converges to $X^\infty$, the quadratic variation (the bracket process) $[X^n]$ also weakly converges to that of the limiting process $[X^\infty]$. (See book limit theorem for stochastic processes, Jacod and Shiryaev, Chapter VI, Theorem 6.26)
My question concerns the predictable quadratic variation (the angle bracket) $\langle X \rangle$:
If $X^n$ weakly converges to $X^\infty$, are there any results about the convergence of the $\langle X^n \rangle$ to $\langle X^\infty \rangle$ in some sense?
I am aware that for a sequence of simple discretizations of continuous processes, the $\langle X^n \rangle_t$ can converge in $L^1$ to the $\langle X^\infty \rangle_t$. The main idea is
$$
\langle X^n \rangle_t-\langle X^\infty \rangle_t=\sum_{i=1}^{nt} \mathbb{E}(\langle X^n \rangle_{\frac{i}{n}}-\langle X^n \rangle_{\frac{i-1}{n}}|\mathcal{F}_{\frac{i-1}{n}})-(\langle X^\infty \rangle_{\frac{i}{n}}-\langle X^\infty \rangle_{\frac{i-1}{n}})
$$
Since $X^n$ is the simple discretization, $\langle X^n \rangle_{\frac{i}{n}}=\langle X^\infty \rangle_{\frac{i}{n}}$. The expectation of the above expression is zero and can be controlled by $\mathbb{E}(\langle X^\infty \rangle_{\frac{i}{n}}-\langle X^\infty \rangle_{\frac{i-1}{n}})$. Therefore, the convergence follows from the continuity of $X^\infty$.
So are there other books or papers that discuss more general results on the convergence of the angle bracket process? Thank you very much!
